# How is my python 3 code different from python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, compiler-errors, sequences

I have been trying to run my code of python 3 on "Dividing Sequences" on python 2 compiler. it compiles correctly but it doesn't show answers requires as it was showing on python 3 compiler.

> What changes I can make in my code to run it on python 2 compiler?

```
n = int(input())
ar = []
bestvals = []
best_stored = []
for x in range(n):
  ar.append(int(input()))
  best_stored.append(0)

best_stored[0] = 1

for i in range(n):
  maxval = 1
  for j in range(i):
    if ar[i] % ar[j] == 0:
      maxval = max(maxval,(best_stored[j])+1)
  best_stored[i] = maxval

print(max(best_stored))
```

The input was

```
9
2 
3 
7 
8 
14 
39 
145 
76 
320
```

and the output for this on pyhton 3 was 3.

Comment: @tamjd1: For `print` with a single value, the parens don't change anything. Besides, you could keep it Py2/Py3 compatible by adding `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of the file, allowing you to use Py3 `print` on Py2.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This code runs just fine on Python 2 for me. There are things you can improve, but it works exactly as given on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line from `n = int(input())` to `n = int(raw_input())`.

Comment: That shouldn't actually matter; it's good practice, but Py2 `input` would `eval` legal `int` values to `int`, and the `int()` wrapping would be redundant, but wouldn't change behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This code should run just fine on Python 2, however `n = int(input())` can be changed to `n = input()`, as `input()` in Python 2 was for numbers whereas in Python 3 it is for strings, and `raw_input()` in Python 2 provided the same functionality that `input()` now does in Python 3.